# Corrupted Excel file getting downloaded through API gateway

Tags: javascript, excel, rest, aws-api-gateway

I am using a lambda function to generate a excel file. I am accessing this generated excel file in my react frontend via API gateway. However when I am trying to download this file in through my frontend, I can't seem to open it. It says that "the given file format does not match its extension". I saw a few related question here in stackoverflow and tried the configuration but I am still not able to resolve this error.

Also my excel file is getting created correctly as just for testing, I tried to save my excel file in my s3 bucket first and download manually from there. I was able to download the correct excel file with expected output in it. However when I send it to the frontend through the API gateway it gets corrupted.

Here is my lambda function code

```
import json

import io
import base64
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation import DataValidation

data = [
    ["HEAD1", "Head2"],
    ["hello", "operating_system"],
    ["durablility", "material"],
    ["longevity", "item_name"],
    
]

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # i generate my workbook correctly using openpyxl
    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    for r in data:
      ws.append(r)
    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    wb.save(buffer)
    excel_final = buffer.getvalue()
    buffer.close()
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        },
        'body': base64.b64encode(excel_final),
        'isBase64Encoded': True
    }
```

Here is how I am fetching it from my frontend , I have tried this multiple options in the request none of them seem to work

```
const requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
       'Accept': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
    }, 
    
  };  

     fetch(url,requestOptions)
     .then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.arrayBuffer();
      }
    })
    .then(blob => {
      const file = new File([blob], "demo.xlsx",{type:"application/xml"})
      const link = document.createElement('a')
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(file)

      link.href = url
      link.download = file.name
      document.body.appendChild(link)
      link.click()
```

Also in my API gateway I have enabled binary media types and set it to `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` still no help.

I am unable to understand what is causing my file to get corrupted. Any help will be appreciated.